# Filtering svn ls --xml for recently modified files without an XML parser

Tags: xml, linux, bash, svn, fedora

I am extremely new to Linux and Bash Scripting and I am struggling a little bit on getting started with it. I have a list of elements in XML, and I would like to only select a few of them. Based on the element with the latest year and latest month (last changed), I want to select by name only those that got changed the last 4 months. Basically I want a list of names of elements used in the last 4 months. I am using **svn ls --xml** to spit the data out in xml and I am trying to pipe it to **grep** to do the above. I can't use an xml parser as that would require me to install it in every system the script will be running on. Here are two of such xml entries:

```
<entry
   kind="directory">
<name>foo</name>
<commit
   revision="69">
<author>myself</author>
<date>2016-05-13T00:21:59.396753Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
<entry
   kind="directory">
<name>bar</name>
<commit
   revision="666">
<author>myself</author>
<date>2013-04-04T01:56:54.484359Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</list>
</lists>
```

Comment: "can't use an XML parser" -- certainly you can; even if you don't have `xmlstarlet`, there are already XML parsers installed on every modern system.

Comment: You have a Python interpreter? It's got *several* different XML libraries built in. You have `xsltproc`? That's got you covered too.

Comment: ...regardless, determining which dates are or are not inside the last N months is not a task `grep` is capable of, but is one the Python runtime or the standard library for XPath (and thus XSLT) includes capabilities for.

Comment: ...moreover, `xsltproc` is used by Subversion's documentation tooling, so unless you're on an OS where it's packaged as a build-time-only dependency, you'll have it everywhere SVN is present (and it's **guaranteed** to be available in the packaging system, or else svn's documentation wouldn't have been able to build).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Horrible, no-good, very-bad answer you asked for

Assuming (and it's an assumption *absolutely not guaranteed to hold in future releases*) that the formatting of this output will remain constant in the future (in ways beyond the well-formedness guarantees provided by the XML specification), and that your filenames will never contain characters that need to be escaped in XML:

```
date_re='^<date>(.*)</date>$'
name_re='^<name>(.*)</name>$'
end_re='^</entry>$'

limit=$(date -d 'now - 4 months' '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') || exit

date=; name=
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ $date_re ]] && date=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  [[ $line =~ $name_re ]] && name=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  [[ $line =~ $end_re && $date && $name ]] && [[ $date > $limit ]] && {
    printf '%s\t%q\n' "$date" "$name"
    date=; name=
  }
done < <(svn ls --xml) | sort -r
```

The output of this will be a stream that looks something like (for your input):

```
2016-05-13T00:21:59.396753Z foo
```

Note that this **will** behave badly if your filenames are at all interesting. Expect `&gt;`, `&amp;`, and similar in your output, whereas the actual filenames contain `>`, `&` or the like. It will also cease to work if future versions of SVN add attributes to these XML tags, which they're entirely allowed to do. Don't do this.

---

#### The Right Thing

...to get the four newest files:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//entry' -v './commit/date' -o $'\t' -v './name' -n \
  | sort -r \
  | head -n 4
```

...now, this is unambiguous only if we assume that Subversion can't store filenames with literal newlines. Fortunately, this is a rule it enforces in practice; thus, everything past the first tab character in this output stream can be safely interpreted as a filesystem component.

---

#### The Right Thing, Portably

The above `xmlstarlet` command is precisely equivalent to using `xsltproc` to apply the following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//entry">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./commit/date"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>        </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./name"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If this is saved as `names-and-dates.xslt`, then:

```
xsltproc names-and-dates.xslt - < <(svn ls --xml) | sort -r | head
```

...will apply it accordingly.

---

#### Footnote: Applying a date cutoff

Replace `head` with `awk -v min_date=$(date -d 'now - 4 months' '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') '($1 < min_date) { exit } { print }'` in the above if you want to enforce a date cutoff rather than taking the last-N approach of `head`, as preferred.

If you want to take four months relative to the first entry, rather than relative to the current date, you could instead pipe the results through the following:

```
{
   read -r date name
   min_date=$(date -d "$date - 4 months" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
   printf '%s\t%s\n' "$date" "$name"
   while read -r date name; do
     [[ $date > $min_date ]] || break
     printf '%s\t%s\n' "$date" "$name"
   done
}
```

Note that this assumes GNU date; adjusting for portability to non-GNU platforms is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: What alternative you believe would be best instead of using GREP? I was thinking about using a command that outputs the elements sorted by changed date and grabbing the last 5 or so. That would suffice for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You'll notice I didn't use `grep` here either, and because I'm putting the changed date *before* the filename in output, you can just pipe straight through `sort`.

Comment: ...if you took out the `limit`-related code (and no longer enforced last-four-months that way), you could pipe the output of this into `head` and that would get you your first several most recently-changed files.

Comment: that said, Doing It Right while using only tools likely to be preinstalled would mean using `xsltproc`, or the Python standard-library XML modules. I'm a fan of using bash where it makes sense, but particularly if you can't install `jq` or `xmlstarlet` and need to parse JSON or XML, it can at times simply be the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: ...the xmlstarlet approach, btw, would be something like: `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//entry' -v './commit/date' -o $'\t' -v './name' -n`. You can ask that to spit out an XSLT template for your command line, so it'll give you something you can use in xsltproc.

Comment: @LinuxLearner, ...and I've done that for you here; see answer as-amended.

Comment: I just noticed. You are using date now. The problem is that there is no guarantee that the system where the script will be running will have it's time updated. I need to use the most updated entry as a reference to start dating back from the 4 months. Any thoughts?

Comment: ...srsly, you can't use `ntpdate`? Anyhow -- it's easy to pick the date from the first line and use that for subsequent ones, but I also hold that that's getting beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: I am not allowed to update the system time or use an XML parsing module. It's frustrating, but these are the constraints I am working with.

Comment: "Not allowed"? Might I ask from where these are enforced? Is this a classroom exercise? In the commercial world, it's often entirely acceptable for infrastructure to refuse to operate without working NTP -- heck, if you're at an AFS site, even your filesystem will fail without time sync.

Comment: (...to roughly explain why that's accepted practice: If you don't have NTP, you don't have accurate datestamps in your logs; if you don't have accurate logging, you don't have auditability; if you don't have auditability, continuing to operate creates liability).

Comment: (To be clear, I'm not encouraging you to update system time from this script; I'm encouraging you to deliver software that clearly documents that it won't work correctly unless system time is accurately maintained. That's a critical distinction: It puts the onus of keeping accurate time on `ntpd` or other daemons maintained by your system administration team, not on any random piece of software that happens to need the clock).

Comment: (...not just AFS, thinking about it -- anyone depending on Zookeeper or a RAFT protocol derivative to elect a master for a distributed block-level filesystem such as GFS2 will be similarly dependent on time sync).

Comment: Thanks for all the insight. I used your arguments to convince my supervisor to enforce all of our machines to have the system time to be updated. She is still reluctant on installing packages (We didn't even have ntp insalled on the fedora machines we are running, so I'm pushing that package as rpms). For security reasons we can't even use yum from the machines. There are about 500 of those running legacy software within the company. It's complicated to explain the specific use of our machines, but it is a very specific purpose system.